# How to extract first number after decimal point in value

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, decimal, truncate

I have an age column which calculates age for each member in my report.The output is a whole number followed by a decimal point and numbers. I would like the first number only right after the decimal point .

I tried trunc but it gives me everything before the decimal and then the number I want after .Then I tried to trunc with a call out with a comma and it doesnt work.

trunc(age,',')

Example -

age 15.7

expected output 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

```
select substr(to_char(15.7,'9999.0'),-1,1) as col from dual
 it will return 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I was able to get the number I wanted substr(to_char(popu.age,'9999.0'),-1,1), with the statement.

Comment: This **doesn't work** for `15.75` as it returns *rounded* number `8`.

Answer (score 2):

Here the *mathematical* answer

- take the decimal part by susbriacting the whole part (trunc).
- multiply by 10 and take the whole part

.

```
with age as (select 15.7231 age from dual)
select trunc(10*(age-trunc(age))) dp1  from age

       DP1
----------
         7
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 10, trunc it and take the remainder of the division by 10.

```
with age as (select 15.7231 age from dual)
select mod(trunc(10*age), 10) dp from age
```

**Output:**

```
DP
--
 7
```